# Cannot compile bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, elsarticle

I'm not sure how to get my bibliography and citation call-outs to be generated a certain way. I'm using an `elsarticle` (Elseiver) template with BibTex and TexStudio. For one thing, my first citation shows up as `[2]`. What I want is an APA format, i.e.) `(Jones et al., 2010)`.

Here's my setup:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\journal{NeuroImage}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{TITLE}
.....
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

What am I missing?? And thank you in advance.

Comment: plainnat is a numerical style, try apalike. But i think Elsevier uses Vancouver referencing only in its journals.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Not quite. First off, `plainnat` can produce both authoryear-style and numeric-style citation call-outs, depending on which option ia passed to the `natbib` package. Second, because the `elsarticle` document class loads `natbib` automatically, it's essential to state the option `authoryear` in the `\documentclass` directive. (That, or run a `\setcitestyle{authoryear}` directive later on somewhere in the preamble...).